CORS problem between localhost and Azure backend
I'm developing a web app with Vue and have also developed a backend with FastAPI, which is already deployed on Azure. Now, from my web app running on localhost, I'd like to call some APIs of the backend. However, when I try, I encounter this error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxxx.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io/api/xxxxx' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

I’ve already tried setting up all the CORS options on the server, like this:
_app = FastAPI(debug=False)
_app.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware, allow_origins=["*"], allow_methods=["*"], allow_headers=["*"])
_app.include_router(api_router, prefix="/api")
uvicorn.run(_app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, log_config=log_config)

but I still get the same error.

Your app has tried to redirect the OPTIONS request for https://xxxxxx.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io/api/xxxxx to somewhere else, which is not allowed - it must respond with a 2xx status code.

So the CORS middleware in FastAPI is not working correctly, because as i understood it should manage all the OPTIONS requests. Any idea about how to solve? Should i define something like that:
@app.options("/{rest_of_path:path}") async def options_handler(request: Request, rest_of_path: str):     return JSONResponse(status_code=204)


Use an explicit list of origins 2) Verify that the (base) origin in your list matches the Origin header sent in the OPTIONS request (use your browser's development tools for this) - this should be https://xxxxxx.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io - protocol and complete host is important.

